# Lightning Web Component - custom tab - not refreshing

Tags: lightning-web-components, tab

I added LWC as Custom tab, But when I moved from another tab(Standard obj tabs-Account/Contacts..) to THIS custom tab. Its not refreshing/reloading. Its showing same data.

Please someone suggest the solution & issue regarding this. Is it issue with LWC?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create Aura Component and put your LWC component inside that aura component. For custom tab, use the aura component.

See code reference

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
 <c:LwcComponent/> 
</aura:component>
```

Comment: It didn't work.. I think it was issue with CSS. 
We used Lightning datatable instead of html table...

But when I open same table in IE, it opened without any issue but CSS isn't applied. Then we came to realize, it might be issue with CSS or Chrome itself...